# Conversion error when comparing field with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me what I am possibly doing wrong in this query? I am getting the error message

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

So I think it does not like the DATEADD part, but I have used that before (not as part of a join) and it worked fine. I can't figure out any other way to filter out for just the past month though. Thank you!

```
SELECT ----
FROM dbo.LocationRevenues AS lr
INNER JOIN dbo.Subscriptions AS sub
  ON (lr.order_number_id = sub._order_number_id_)
WHERE sub._starts_at_ BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
  AND lr.subchannel_code = 'Channel'
  AND lr.location_name != 'LocationA';
```

Comment: The error complains about *strings*, not `DATEADD`. What's the type of the unconventionally named `_starts_at_` ? If it's not a date-related type, there's a serious design bug. Dates aren't strings. You can't store dates as formatted strings without risking bad data or worse, incorrect parsing. You can't say what `04/07/2022` means by looking at it

Comment: Post the table definitions. At the very least `Subscriptions`

Comment: Table definitions for both tables, please.

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` means that a string field contains something that can't be parsed as a date. Perhaps it's `'Banana'`. Or it may be something *very* bad, like `31/12/2022`. That's bad because it means dates are stored as localized strings but parsed using a different locale. In the best case you'll get an error. In bad cases you'll get the wrong date, resulting in missed results and some pretty bad real-life consequences. If `10/01/2022` is a bill expiration date some unfortunate person could get an 8-month fine

Comment: It's pretty clear that _starts_at_ is not a datetime.  Instead of "fixing" it and converting it to a datetime, figure out the desired range of strings before the query.  Then use "sub._starts_at_ BETWEEN @start AND @end" so that an index can be used.

Comment: @RandyinMarin: You assume there is an index, that can be used.

Comment: @Luuk I've worked with developers for 20 years.  I assume an index does not exist.  :)  One might be added someday.

Comment: When (trying to) convert a string to a date, there are [several](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/) ways to do it, but [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) might be the best one.

Comment: I'd argue for `TRY_CONVERT`, as you can specify a style for the conversion value

Comment: If going down the road of casting the string to a datetime, one trick for development is to test it on all data of the table.  For example, SELECT _starts_at_, convert_code_here FROM dbo.Subscriptions.  You can also validate the format of the string on all the data via a similar query to see if it's consistent.  Comparing strings to strings is better if it's an option.  If in development, should _starts_at_ be a date or datetime instead of a string?

Comment: And don't use between for dates, its behaviour is not intuitive. Instead use `mydate >= @StartDate and mydate < @EndDate` where `@EndDate` is the day after the last date you want.

Comment: We need a [mre] for this, including sample data which can produce the issue.

Comment: @RandyinMarin It depends. If dates are stored in `mm/dd/yyyy`, then it wouldn't be possible to generate proper start and end dates for `between`.

Answer (score 1):

This script will find the problem for you.

```
SELECT sub.starts_at_
FROM Subscriptions sub
WHERE ISDATE(sub.starts_at_) = 0
```

Add another column such as the PK to the select list to help track down the actual row.